# Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode

I can't find the error in the code. It says "thread1 signal SIGABRT".

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

that was the line the error read Thread 1:signal SIGABRT.

Comment: here is the view controller.swift

Answer (score 2):

One of your outlets probably has been disconnected (removed). Check all your outlets in the storyboard to see if they are still linked.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me - I had a similar problem and it was due to a typo on the name of the folder containing my .swift files... verify your folder name so the route you call is correct.

In my case (below) the "UserLoginAndRegistration" Folder Name had a typo, which I fixed, and now it works great.

[image]

Comment: This is not a question, it is an answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an IBOutlet declared which isn't connected to anything.